# Why don't my artifacts published during the build using the publishArtifacts service message show up in TeamCity?

Tags: nunit, teamcity

I am creating a screenshot when my NUnit end-to-end test fails and I am trying to publish it with TeamCity (build agent and server both running on Windows) using the following service message (as described [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-PublishingArtifactswhiletheBuildisStillinProgress)) which I am writing with `Console.WriteLine` from an NUnit test:

```
##teamcity[publishArtifacts 'C:\BuildAgent\work\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\Path\To\My\Stuff\fail.png']
```

I see the line in the build log:

```
------- Stdout: -------
##teamcity[publishArtifacts 'C:\BuildAgent\work\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\Path\To\My\Stuff\fail.png']
```

But TeamCity is not picking up the file, or at least it is not showing up in the build artifacts. How do I make this work?

Comment: Is it possible that your message contains some characters which must be escaped: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-ServiceMessages ?

Comment: No, as long as `:` and `\\` are OK (and they appear to be) then that isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using relative paths. Teamcity should resolve them against build working directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Console.Write` instead of `Console.WriteLine` (see below).

Anyway, I guess TeamCity don't trap these messages because they are 'test reports' and appended in the buildlog as text output.

My feeling is they are not parsed and then not interpreted by the Build Script Interaction behavior because of the way they are flushed into the build log.

From the [Build Script Interaction](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity) (TC 7) :

> Service messages are used to pass commands/build information to
>   TeamCity server from the build script. In order to be processed by
>   TeamCity they should be printed into standard output stream of the
>   build (otherwise, if the output is not in the service message syntax,
>   it should appear in the build log). **A single service message should
>   not contain a newline character inside it, it should not span across
>   multiple lines**.

You should put your test artifacts in a specific folder and delay the publish after the tests.

Note that if you don't need to resolve artifact dynamically, you should use the simpliest way : the `Artifact paths` in the build configuration general settings.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` adds a newline *after* the service message, so that isn't the problem. As the quote says, the service messages just need to be written to the standard output stream of the build - how they are flushed is irrelevant. Unfortunately I don't have access to the project any more to try anything else :(

Comment: Yep about the WriteLine it was just to try. It doesn't work on my TC either. About the flush of the NUnit output, it is not totally irrevelant because **tests outputs are not standard output**, every test framework append its own console listener. If you run the `nunit-console.exe` you'll see that the `WriteLine` from your test appears somehow in bulk. Also, TeamCity use its own NUnit runner. Note that what you are trying doesn't work with MSTest either. You can see something like `[Test Output]` after your test name and before its output also, it may fail because of this text. Probably a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Use the NuGet package provided by JetBrains, this takes care of all the subtleties

```
NuGet Install TeamCity.ServiceMessages
```

On GitHub: https://github.com/JetBrains/TeamCity.ServiceMessages